# Name a functor of functor

Tags: haskell, gadt

I have been playing around with updating [Reflex](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex) to [DMap 0.2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map-0.2.0.1) and ran into an issue translating one of the embedded functors.

Specifically it previously used a GADT to encode an `a -> [WeakSubscriber a]` relationship like so:

```
data FanSubscriberKey k a where
  FanSubscriberKey :: k a -> FanSubscriberKey k [WeakSubscriber a]
```

However in the newest version of DMap you can just embed a functor directly. I initially lifted the `[]` out of the above but realized that since I had a functor of a functor, I had a functor and wanted to eliminate the extra data all together. Unfortunately I cannot figure out a way to describe the above mapping without using a newtype. `newtype WeakSubscriberList a = WeakSubscriberList [WeakSubscriber a]` would solve the problem but would require wrapping and unwrapping the newtype.

Previous research points to this being considered a type-level lambda which is usually disallowed but the transformation here seemed simple enough that it could be possible, especially since I am not looking to define an instance or anything like that.

Using DMap 0.1 we can store a `FanSubscriberKey k` and have its value be a `[WeakSubscriber a]` in a `DMap (FanSubscriberKey k)` with its key being wrapped in the `FanSubscriberKey` constructor. In DMap 0.2 if I defined the above `newtype` I could similarly say `DMap k WeakSubscriberList` and get a similar result having an unwrapped key but a value wrapped in `WeakSubscriberList`. However what I would like to say is `DMap k [WeakSubscriber]` but that obviously won't work since `[]` is kind `* -> *` and `WeakSubscriber` is kind `* -> *`. If there were a type level `.` such that `[] '. WeakSubscriber` compiled that would do the trick but it similarly does not exist. I also tried a type alias but `type WeakSubscriberList a = [WeakSubscriber a]` requires that `a` be specified wherever `WeakSubscriberList` is used.

Comment: Can you make this more specific and concrete? Perhaps include some more relevant definitions and code?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question as well, but maybe [`Data.Functor.Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) is the answer.  It is a `newtype` though and requires wrapping and unwrapping.

Comment: @LuisCasillas: That is likely the best answer, I had found it before but discounted it since it wasn't a clean solution, but it is better than a `newtype` that is defined.

Comment: As Haskell code becomes more abstract, newtype wrapping becomes more common.  Maybe just take the hit... using [newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype) library to make your life easier if you like.

Comment: @LuisCasillas: I went with Compose so added it as an answer, if you want to create an answer I will mark it as correct, since an ideal answer doesn't look to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Data.Functor.Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) is a straightforward way of indirectly avoiding the `newtype`. It still involves a `newtype`, since that is how `Compose` is defined, but a new one doesn't need to be defined.

The example above becomes `DMap k (Compose [] WeakSubscriber)`.